# Plotting a non-linear trendline on a logarithmic plot in R

Tags: r, plot

I have some peak annual discharge data from a local stream and want to create a flood frequency chart. Here's a sample of my data:

```
#Set up maximum flow data
flow=sample(seq(10,1000,20),100,replace=TRUE)
#Order flows from largest to smallest
flow=as.data.frame(flow[order(flow, decreasing=TRUE)])
names(flow)="max"
#rank flows from largest to smallest
flow$"rank"=seq(1,nrow(flow),1)
#Calculate the return interval in years
flow$"RI"=(nrow(flow)+1)/flow$"rank"
plot(flow$"max"~flow$"RI",type='p', log='xy',xlab='Return Interval', ylab='Max flow')
```

Next I was able to figure out the logarithmic function for the line of best fit with:

```
logMod = nls( max ~ (a*log10(RI)+b), data=flow, 
    start = list(a = 0, b = 0))
```

Now my real question is how do I plot this line on the log-log plot that was created above without having to check every time what the variables created in my nls function were? I'd like some way to quickly plot out the line-of-best-fit, and if I don't like it, go change the nls function to a new kind of non-linear equation. For example if the logarithmic line doesn't line up well with the data I could change the formula in the nls function to an exponential or polynomial function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `predict()` for this

```
x <- seq(min(flow$RI), max(flow$RI), length.out=100)
y <- predict(logMod, data.frame(RI=x))
lines(x,y, col="red")
```